# I don't know why my C++ class won't print

Tags: c++, class

I'm new to coding and trying to figure out why my classes don't seem to work. 
My program needs to create 4 books and display them from a main program.

I've been scratching my head over this for the past day and a half and think I'm not referring to one of the objects correctly... I can get my code to compile but it just spits out huge numbers.

```html
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class book
{
public:
    book(string bn, int pn);
    string getName();
    int getPageNum();
    void setName(string bookName);
    void setPageNum(int pNum);
    string bn;
    int pn;
 string bookName;
 int pNum;
};
book::book(string bookName, int pNum) //provides framework for final print/input
{
 bookName = bn;
 pNum = pn;
}
void book::setName(string bookName) //set book's name
{
    bookName=bn;
}
void book::setPageNum(int pNum) //set book's page number
{
    pNum=pn;
}
void print(book b) //printing function
{
    cout<<"Your book is called: "<< b.bookName <<", and you're on page: "<< b.pNum;
}
int main()
{
book b1 = book("The Odyssey", 5);
book b2 = book("To Kill a Mockingbird", 153);
book b3 = book("Pride and Prejudice", 88);
book b4 = book("The Great Gatsby", 17);
print(b1);
print(b2);
print(b3);
print(b4);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by reducing the code until you have the smallest possible code you can come up with that reproduces the error. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Alternatively, step through with a debugger and compare actual and expected results of each line. See [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises when you are assigning values. One example:

```
void book::setName(string bookName) //set book's name
{
    bookName=bn;
}
```

Notice here you are passing the argument as `bookName`, and your class has a member called `bn`. You should be assigning bookName to bn, not the other way round. It should be `bn=bookName`. This problem is in many of your functions. Also, member `pNum` is redundant.

The modified (corrected) code :http://ideone.com/Ha5Dhn

Answer (score 1):

You swapped the assignments in the constructor and the other member functions.
Also the member variables   `bookName` and `pNum` were not needed.
Here is the fixed code:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class book
{
public:
    book(string bn, int pn);
    string getName();
    int getPageNum();
    void setName(string bookName);
    void setPageNum(int pNum);
    string bn;
    int pn;

};
book::book(string bookName, int pNum) //provides framework for final print/input
{
    bn = bookName;
    pn = pNum;
}
void book::setName(string bookName) //set book's name
{
    bn = bookName;
}
void book::setPageNum(int pNum) //set book's page number
{
    pn = pNum;
}
void print(book b) //printing function
{
    cout<<"Your book is called: "<< b.bn <<", and you're on page: "<< b.pn<<endl;
}
int main()
{
book b1 = book("The Odyssey", 5);
book b2 = book("To Kill a Mockingbird", 153);
book b3 = book("Pride and Prejudice", 88);
book b4 = book("The Great Gatsby", 17);
print(b1);
print(b2);
print(b3);
print(b4);
return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps :)